# Laravel 5 Pagination with Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm making a Laravel Pagination based from my query result and be rendered in my view. I'm following this guide http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination but I get an error:

```
Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object
```

I'm using query builder so I think that should be ok? Here's my code

```
public function getDeliveries($date_from, $date_to)
{
    $query = "Select order_confirmation.oc_number as oc,
    order_confirmation.count as cnt,
    order_confirmation.status as stat,
    order_confirmation.po_number as pon,
    order_summary.date_delivered as dd,
    order_summary.delivery_quantity as dq,
    order_summary.is_invoiced as iin,
    order_summary.filename as fn,
    order_summary.invoice_number as inum,
    order_summary.oc_idfk as ocidfk,
    order_summary.date_invoiced as di
    FROM
    order_confirmation,order_summary
    where order_confirmation.id = order_summary.oc_idfk";

    if (isset($date_from)) {
        if (!empty($date_from))
        {
            $query .= " and order_summary.date_delivered >= '".$date_from."'";
        }
    }

    if (isset($date_to)) {
        if (!empty($date_to)) 
        {
            $query .= " and order_summary.date_delivered <= '".$date_to."'";
        }
    }

    $query.="order by order_confirmation.id ASC";

    $data = DB::connection('qds106')->select($query)->paginate(15);
    return $data;
}
```

However when I remove the paginate(15); it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem with queryBuilder since get() works after whereIn()->get() but paginate() does not. Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

in the doc at this page: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination
we can see that we are not forced to use eloquent.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
```

but, be sure you don't make a groupBy in your query because, the paginate method uses it.

after i'm no sure you can use paginate with query builder ( `select($query)` )

--- edit

You can create collection an use the paginator class :

```
$collection = new Collection($put_your_array_here);

// Paginate
$perPage = 10; // Item per page
$currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1; // url.com/test?page=2
$pagedData = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
$collection= Paginator::make($pagedData, count($collection), $perPage);
```

and in your view just use `$collection->render();`

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getDeliveries($date_from, $date_to)
{
    $query="your_query_here";
    $deliveries = DB::select($query);

    $deliveries = collect($deliveries);
    $perPage = 10;
    $currentPage = \Input::get('page') ?: 1;
    $slice_init = ($currentPage == 1) ? 0 : (($currentPage*$perPage)-$perPage);
    $pagedData = $users->slice($slice_init, $perPage)->all();
    $deliveries = new LengthAwarePaginator($pagedData, count($deliveries), $perPage, $currentPage);
    $deliveries ->setPath('set_your_link_page');
    return $deliveries;
 }
```

Comment: So, if I have a table with one million rows that I would like to paginate, I have to fetch the whole million? Does not seem to be a good approach

Answer (score 1):

You set it by using the custom pagination..

```
$query = "Your Query here";

$page = 1;
$perPage = 5;
$query = DB::select($query);
$currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
$pagedData = array_slice($query, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
$query =  new Paginator($pagedData, count($query), $perPage);
$query->setPath('Your Url');

$this->data['query'] = $query;

return view('Your_view_file', $this->data, compact('query'));
```

Here you can specify the path by using the `setpath()`.

In your **View**

```
@foreach($query as $rev)
//Contents
@endforeach
<?php echo $Reviews->appends($_REQUEST)->render(); ?>
```

The `appends` will append the data.

Thank you.

Comment: Again, you take ALL rows and filter them afterwards, I would definitely do the limitation on the database

Answer (score 1):

this is the way i did, it use query builder and get the same result with pagination

```
$paginateNumber = 20;

    $key = $this->removeAccents(strip_tags(trim($request->input('search_key', ''))));
    $package_id = (int)$request->input('package_id', 0);
    $movieHasTrailer = MovieTrailer::select('movie_id')->where('status','!=','-1')->distinct('movie_id')->get();

    $movieIds = array();

    foreach ($movieHasTrailer as $index => $value) {
        $movieIds[] = $value->movie_id;
    }


    $keyparams = array();
    $packages = Package::select('package_name','id')->get();

    $whereClause = [
        ['movie.status', '!=', '-1'],
        ['movie_trailers.status', '!=', '-1']
    ];

    if(!empty($key)){
        $whereClause[] = ['movie.title', 'like', '%'.$key.'%'];
        $keyparams['search_key'] = $key;  
    }

    if($package_id !== 0){
        $whereClause[] = ['movie.package_id', '=', $package_id];
        $keyparams['package_id'] = $package_id;  
    }



    $movies = DB::table('movie')
            ->leftJoin('movie_package','movie.package_id','=','movie_package.id')
            ->leftJoin('movie_trailers','movie.id','=','movie_trailers.movie_id')
            ->where($whereClause)
            ->whereIn('movie.id',$movieIds)
            ->select('movie.*','movie_package.package_name','movie_trailers.movie_id as movie_id', 
                DB::raw('count(*) as total_trailers, movie_id')
            )
            ->groupBy('movie.id')
            ->paginate($paginateNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hydrate, you can do this...

```
    $pages = DB::table('stuff')
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate(24, ['stuff.id']);

    $stuffs = Stuff::hydrate($pages->items());

    return view('stuff.index')->with('stuffs', $stuffs)->with('pages', $pages)
```

$stuffs will contain your model object, $pages will contain your pagination, probably not the most efficient, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
// import those Class into your Laravel Controller
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

// In your public function

$query = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM your_table"));

$collection = new Collection($query);
 
// Paginate
        
$perPage = 10; // Item per page
        
$currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1;
        
$pagedData = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
        
$pagination = new Paginator($pagedData, $perPage);
        
return response()->json([
  $pagination
], 200);
```

Comment: I based into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964230/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-pagination-paginatormake and the Bouhnosaure answer

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please consider adding some explanation.