# Laravel enable pagination for DB::raw queries

Tags: mysql, pagination, laravel-5.4

I have below raw query which need to be pagination enabled. Should I have to implement manual pagination or can I use built it pagination method? If I can use built-in pagination method, please explain how can I get it done since I tried several time with no luck.

```
$sql = 'select t1.rownum, t2.rownum, t1.logged_on, t1.reading, (t1.reading - t2.reading) as diff
            from (
                select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, date(t.logged_at) as logged_on, t.reading
                from parameter_log_tab t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
                where t.site_id = ?
                order by t.logged_at desc ) t1
            left join (
                select @rowno := @rowno + 1 AS rownum, date(t.logged_at) as logged_on, t.reading
                from parameter_log_tab t, (SELECT @rowno := 0) r
                where t.site_id = ?
                order by t.logged_at desc) t2
            on t1.rownum = t2.rownum - 1';
$result = DB::select($sql, [$site_id, $site_id]);
```

Comment: If you have a raw query, you're responsible for implementing your own pagination. Add a `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` with placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create pagination yourself. May be you are looking something like this.

```
$collection = new Collection($put_your_array_here);

// Paginate
$perPage = 10; // Item per page
$currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1; // url.com/test?page=2
$pagedData = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
$collection= Paginator::make($pagedData, count($collection), $perPage);
```

Here a stack-overflow link: 
[Laravel 5 Pagination with Query Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861378/laravel-5-pagination-with-query-builder)