# How to use laravel pagination with query builder

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel pagination but it is not working with query builder i have also refer the every answer of below stack url but it is also not working every answer showing a 
new error.Please help me to resolve this problem how i can used pagination with
laravel query builder.I am using 5.3 version of laravel.
Stack referal link=[Laravel 5 Pagination with Query Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861378/laravel-5-pagination-with-query-builder)

```
 public function ajaxPagination(Request $request)

{

    $query="SELECT users.`id`,users.`email`,users.`u_firstname`,users.`u_lastname`,users.`u_dob`,users.`u_mobile`,user_roles.`ur_role_id`,UCASE(master_roles.`role_name`) as roles,case users.`u_status` when '0' then 'Inactive' when '1' then 'Active' when '4' then 'Deactivate' end as status FROM `users` inner join user_roles on user_roles.`ur_user_id`=users.`id` inner join master_roles on user_roles.`ur_role_id`=master_roles.`role_id` where users.`id`!='$id' and users.`u_status`!='3' order by users.`id` desc";

     $items = DB::select(DB::raw($query))->paginate(20);

     var_dump($items);
    die;
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        return view('data', compact('items'));

    }

    return view('items',compact('items'));

}
```

**Error while using the above code**
Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: What `var_dump($items);` returns ?

Comment: it returns nothing before this page will show the above error Call to a member function paginate() on array.

Comment: remove the `->paginate(20)1 and put `print_r` and check what it returns?

Comment: showing array with object ex:Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [u_username] => admin [email] => admin@gmail.com [u_emal_verified] => 1 [password] => $2y$10$o9FzOxa5k4hrU4O.0bBOvOnMfX6gyo8GJIajq025u6mDJ4EAqbK1C )