# How to convert normal search query in to laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have written a normal search query and it is working properly fine but i have
to implement laravel pagination in my project but laravel pagination is not working with normal query hence i want to convert my search query in to laravel query using query builder.

My Normal search query is:-

```
 $query="SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT users.`id`,users.`email`,users.`u_firstname`,users.`u_lastname`,users.`u_dob`,users.`u_mobile`,user_roles.`ur_role_id`,UCASE(master_roles.`role_name`) as roles,case users.`u_status` when '0' then 'Inactive' when '1' then 'Active' when '4' then 'Deactivate' end as status,users.`u_status` FROM `users` inner join user_roles on user_roles.`ur_user_id`=users.`id` inner join master_roles on user_roles.`ur_role_id`=master_roles.`role_id`) t WHERE (t.status LIKE '$search%' or t.u_firstname like '$search%' or t.u_lastname like '$search%' or t.email like '$search%' or t.u_mobile like '$search%' or t.u_dob like '$search%' or t.roles like '$search%') and t.id!='$id' and t.u_status!='3'";
```

I want to convert my query in this form i have fetched the all result on which i have to applied searching but i am not getting how to applied search with all columns i a not able to integrate searching concept in the below query like user type varun then it will search from the all column and give only that result:-

```
   $post = DB::table('users')
                ->join('user_roles','users.id','=','user_roles.ur_user_id')
                ->join('master_roles','user_roles.ur_role_id','=','master_roles.role_id')
                ->select('users.id','users.email','users.u_firstname','users.u_lastname','users.u_dob','users.u_mobile','user_roles.ur_role_id','master_roles.role_name as roles',DB::raw('(CASE WHEN users.u_status ="0"  THEN "Inactive"  when "1" then "Active" END) AS status'))
                ->where('users.id','!=',$id)
                ->get();
```

after runing the above laravel query i got below output and now i have to
applied searching part in it;-

```
..............................................................................
 id     email          u_firstname     u_lastname     roles      status  
 ..........................................................................
  1   a@gmail.com        a              b          seller         Active
  2   b@gmail.com        c              d          Buyer          Inactive
```

Comment: just use DB::raw

Comment: yes but after this i am not able to use inbuilt pagination of laravel like this $post = DB::select(DB::raw($query))->pagination(5); it give me error, i want to convert normal query to use pagination of laravel.

Comment: give me error means nothing can you please explain what error you get ?

Comment: i have also posted a question for this you can verify how i can use normal query for pagination https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117885/how-to-use-laravel-pagination-with-query-builder?noredirect=1#comment79198575_46117885

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orWhere` like this

```
$query = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_roles','users.id','=','user_roles.ur_user_id')
    ->join('master_roles','user_roles.ur_role_id','=','master_roles.role_id');
    $query->where(function($query)use($search){
        $query->orwhere('t.status','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
        $query->orwhere('t.u_firstname','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
        $query->orwhere('t.u_lastname','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
        $query->orwhere('t.email','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
        $query->orwhere('t.u_mobile','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
        $query->orwhere('t.u_dob','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
        $query->orwhere('t.roles','LIKE','%'.trim($search).'%');
    });

$query->select('users.id','users.email','users.u_firstname','users.u_lastname','users.u_dob','users.u_mobile','user_roles.ur_role_id','master_roles.role_name as roles',DB::raw('(CASE WHEN users.u_status ="0"  THEN "Inactive"  when "1" then "Active" END) AS status'));
$query->where('users.id','!=',$id);
$query->where('t.u_status','!=',3);
$post = $query->get();
```

Comment: above query is showing error:- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE).

Comment: Just forgot to add `;` at the end now try

Comment: what error and in which line ? try to add quotes here as well `"3"`, `$query->where('t.u_status','!=',"3");`

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154313/laraval-query-builder please join this room so that i can tell you the exact error

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.u_firstname' in 'where clause'

Comment: Use table name instead `t`

Comment: but it is not working with status because i have applied case in status and when i give users.status in query it is showing Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.status' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Paginator yourself - [check the pagination manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Also I would suggest to use [full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) or even better a custom search engine instead of `LIKE = '%text%'`